# Django Generate Custom ID base on Selected Fields

Tags: python, django

I want to generate a custom transaction ID  when new record comes into database base on selected Forms fields. The format should be

2020/John-UK/1012/001,
2020/John-Uk/1012/002,

Where 2020 is the season, John is the supplier name, UK is  location, 1012 is the date, 001 is count for the day.

The count should always start with 001 and increase base on supplier, location and date. Example if the same supplier brings goods the following day from same location the ID should be

2020/John-UK/1112/001

If from different location and same date the ID will be

2020/John-US/1112/001

```
models.py

class Goods_Supply(BaseModel):
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="_", blank=True)
    supplier_name = models.ForeignKey(adminModels.Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    season = models.ForeignKey( adminModels.Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey( adminModels.Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    transaction_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
     quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self. transaction_id
```

class Location(BaseModel):

```
location_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.location
```

class Supplier(BaseModel):

```
supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
license = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="_")
prefix = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="_")
rep = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="_")
phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="_")
email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="_")
status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.supplier_name






forms.py

class GoodSupplyForms(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Models.Goods_Supply
        fields = ["transaction_id", "supplier_name", "season", " location", "transaction_date”, “quantity”]


goods_supply.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
import CMCADMIN.models as adminModels
from SS.models import Goods_Supply
from SS.forms import GoodSupplyForms
from django.urls import reverse


def get_post_handler(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return get(request)
    else:
        return post(request)


def get(request):
    template = loader.get_template("SS/goods_supply.html")
    goodssupply = Goods_Supply.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(ss_registrations, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {'goodssupply': page_obj, 'adminModels': adminModels}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        goodsForm = GoodSupplyForms(request.POST)
        if goodsForm.is_valid():
            goodsForm.save()

            print('Success')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("SS:goods_supply”))

        else:
            return HttpResponse(goodsForm..errors.as_json())

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("SS:goods_supply”))
```

Comment: Please Share models of Location and Supplier

Comment: I have share the Location & Supplier Models please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have to override the save method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            year, month, date = self.transaction_date.year, self.transaction_date.month, self.transaction_date.day 
            count = Goods_Supply.objects.filter(supplier_name=self.supplier_name, transaction_date=self.transaction_date,location__location_name=self.location.location_name).count() + 1
            total_count = "{0:04d}".format(count)
            self.transaction_id = "{}/{}-{}/{}{}/{}".format(year, self.supplier_name.supplier_name, self.location.location_name, month, date, total_count)

        super(Goods_Supply, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. The Code worked, however the count continues if the date change. I want the count to start at 001 when the date or supplier or season change. Also if all the three parameters (date,supplier and season) changes the count should start at 001 base on a given date.

Comment: Example 

Day one 
 
2020/John-Uk/1712/001,
2020/John-Uk/1712/002 and so on. (same supplier and date.)

2020/John-US/1712/001 (same supplier and date different location)
2019/John-US/1712/001 (same supplier and date different season)

2020/Eve-UK/1712/001 and so on. (different suppler, same date and season)

Day Two

2020/John-Uk/1812/001 and counting.  (same supplier and season different date)